# How to make Tic Tac Toe text in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am making an Addon to my chatbot on the website https://chatRoomBot.n8thedev.repl.co and when I use the following code >>>

```
else if (newChat.textContent.toLowerCase().includes("ttt") == true){
      createBotChat(" 1  |  2  |  3 " + "\n" + " --------" + "\n" + " 4  |  5  |  6 " + "\n" + "--------" + "\n" + " 7  |  8  |  9 ");
      if (newChat.textContent.toLowerCase().includes("1") == true) {
        createBotChat(" X  |  2  |  3 " + "\n" + " --------" + "\n" + " 4  |  5  |  6 " + "\n" + "--------" + "\n" + " 7  |  8  |  9 ");
      } else if (newChat.textContent.toLowerCase().includes("2") == true) {
        createBotChat(" 1  |  X  |  3 " + "\n" + " --------" + "\n" + " 4  |  5  |  6 " + "\n" + "--------" + "\n" + " 7  |  8  |  9 ");
      } else if (newChat.textContent.toLowerCase().includes("3") == true) {
        createBotChat(" 1  |  2  |  X " + "\n" + " --------" + "\n" + " 4  |  5  |  6 " + "\n" + "--------" + "\n" + " 7  |  8  |  9 ");
      } else if (newChat.textContent.toLowerCase().includes("4") == true) {
        createBotChat(" 1  |  2  |  3 " + "\n" + " --------" + "\n" + " X  |  5  |  6 " + "\n" + "--------" + "\n" + " 7  |  8  |  9 ");
      } else if (newChat.textContent.toLowerCase().includes("5") == true) {
        createBotChat(" 1  |  2  |  3 " + "\n" + " --------" + "\n" + " 4  |  X  |  6 " + "\n" + "--------" + "\n" + " 7  |  8  |  9 ");
      } else if (newChat.textContent.toLowerCase().includes("6") == true) {
        createBotChat(" 1  |  2  |  3 " + "\n" + " --------" + "\n" + " 4  |  5  |  X " + "\n" + "--------" + "\n" + " 7  |  8  |  9 ");
      } else if (newChat.textContent.toLowerCase().includes("7") == true) {
        createBotChat(" 1  |  2  |  3 " + "\n" + " --------" + "\n" + " 4  |  5  |  6 " + "\n" + "--------" + "\n" + " X  |  8  |  9 ");
      } else if (newChat.textContent.toLowerCase().includes("8") == true) {
        createBotChat(" 1  |  2  |  3 " + "\n" + " --------" + "\n" + " 4  |  5  |  6 " + "\n" + "--------" + "\n" + " 7  |  X  |  9 ");
      } else if (newChat.textContent.toLowerCase().includes("9") == true) {
        createBotChat(" 1  |  2  |  3 " + "\n" + " --------" + "\n" + " 4  |  5  |  6 " + "\n" + "--------" + "\n" + " 7  |  8  |  X ");
      }
    }
```

And if you go onto the website you can see the error when type 'ttt' for tic tac toe. It types the normal game but also types another later version and I don't know why. Can someone please help me in on a time crunch.

Comment: you have to separate case when textContext equals ttt and textContext contains ttt. the former one starts game and latter one continues game.

Comment: Which later version does it type?

Comment: @TalGlik the 4th one